# Why there is spaces in the output of my array

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I am trying to get list of specifics names from a web site to ultimately output them in a file. The website I am parsing is  [this one](https://translate.google.com/translate?sl=auto&tl=en&js=y&prev=_t&hl=en&ie=UTF-8&u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.prenom-marocain.com&edit-text=)

The code is certainly not perfect, but what is puzzling me is why is there spaces in the output between each group of names?

```
 from urllib.request import urlopen
 from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bS
 import re

# get the internals links  

    def get_internals():
        array=[]
        html = urlopen("http://127.0.0.1/www.prenom-marocain.com")
        soup = bS(html,"lxml")
        azlinks = soup.find("nav", {"class":"page-nav"}).findAll("a", {"href":re.compile("^p.*$")})
        for links in azlinks:
            array.append(links.attrs['href'])

        return array


    # The function for fetching the names 

    def fetch_name(url):
        array=[]
        html = urlopen("http://127.0.0.1/www.prenom-marocain.com/"+url)
        soup = bS(html, "lxml")
        for child in soup.findAll("ul", {"class":"arrow"}):
            array.append(child.getText())

        return array


    alpha_array = get_internals()


    first_names=[]

    for links in alpha_array:
        first_name += (fetch_name(links))


    for names in first_names:
        print(names)
    `
```

How can I get rid of the spaces in the output ?
Is it normal behavior for the array.append method ? 
And what is the best way to store everything in a file ?
Thanks in advance !

Comment: It seems that your code currently works, and you are looking to improve it. Generally these questions are too opinionated for this site, but you might find better luck at [codereview.se]. Remember to read [their requirements](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) as they are a bit more strict than this site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your function `fetch_name()` you are adding to the array empty strings (on pages without any name, the `<ul class="arrow">` is empty string). With simple if you can filter it away, this will print all names without spaces:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bS
import re

# get the internals links

def get_internals():
    array=[]
    html = urlopen("http://www.prenom-marocain.com")
    soup = bS(html,"lxml")
    azlinks = soup.find("nav", {"class":"page-nav"}).findAll("a", {"href":re.compile("^p.*$")})
    for links in azlinks:
        array.append(links.attrs['href'])
    return array

# The function for fetching the names

def fetch_name(url):
    array=[]
    html = urlopen("http://www.prenom-marocain.com/"+url)
    soup = bS(html, "lxml")
    for child in soup.findAll("ul", {"class":"arrow"}):
        if not child.text.strip():
            break
        array.append(child.text.strip())
    return array

alpha_array = get_internals()

first_names=[]
for links in alpha_array:
    first_names += (fetch_name(links))

for names in first_names:
    print(names)
```

Comment: thank you I fixed the output using something like that `for ul in soup.findAll('ul'):
    for li in ul.findAll('li'):
        for a in li.findAll('a'):
            if a.text is not None:
                print(a.text)`

Comment: @eDen Do you mean hot to escape `while True` infinite loop? You have multiple ways: using `break` - this will break the loop and program will continue afterwards, using `return` - if the `while True` is inside function, the function will ends and value will will be returned, and throwing exception `raise` - in that case the program jumps to next `except` statement.

Comment: Yes but in the context of the get_int() function in the post. I can't understand how when an int is given to the function, the True get changed to false in that case.

Comment: @eDen You need to ask in the other question, comments under other questions/answers aren't appropriate place to discuss it.